# Problem while creating the NLP model using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tokenize, word-embedding

I have created a spam classifier model using tensorflow.. ( tokenization , embedding layer and lstm ).

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(voc_size,32,input_length=sent_len))
model.add(LSTM(units=128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))
```

I have trained the model with my data and got an accuracy of about 97-98%.

I processed my data using the below function.

```
def process(data):
    data=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]'," ",data)
    data=data.lower()
    data=data.split()
    data=[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in data if word not in set(stopword)]
    data=" ".join(data)
    return data
```

I have predicted my new custom input as :

```
def predict(data):
    data=[process(sent) for sent in data]
    data=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
    data=pad_sequences(data,maxlen=sent_len,padding='pre')
    pred=(mymodel.predict(data)>0.5).astype('int32').tolist()
    return pred

data=input()
predict(data)
```

But I am receiving the msg as non-spam for every msg I input..no matter what I enter.[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk1b9.png)

I don't know what is happening. I am not able to deploy such a model.

Comment: I am making a guess here since i dont have the full code but if u look at input() returns a string not a list of str so when u for loop it becomes only a list of str e.g (hi -> ['h', 'i']

Comment: An important point has been mentioned in the above comment but as a side note, you must know ham/spam datasets are highly unbalanced so the `accuracy` score is not the best option for measuring the performance.

Comment: "I have trained the model with my data" - are you sure these data you used are sufficient to train a well-generalizing model? The more data you have the better is the model.

Comment: This issue might be due to unbalanced dataset or model that you created, which cannot possibly predict what you want. Select proper learning rate / regularization parameters. Use proper activation function based on your data type. Thanks!